# Automatically run Django project in Debug when in PyCharm

Tags: django, pycharm

Is it possible to run my Django project in `DEBUG` mode, when in PyCharm? If not in PyCharm, say in production, then of course the `DEBUG` mode should not be `True`. How can this be done most neatly?

Comment: I've deleted my anwear I need a few detials.
1. You use community edition or enterprise one?
2. How do you run your project normally? Is it in docker, remote debugger or something?

Comment: Professional edition, I run my project simply on my desktop, no docker or remote debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be setting up your `settings.py` to read the `DEBUG` value from the environment variables, then tell PyCharm to run with that env var set.

```
import os
# ...
DEBUG = (True if os.environ.get('DEBUG') else False)
```

and set `DEBUG=1` in PyCharm's Edit Configurations... window.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your run configuration and set an environment variable called `DJANGO_DEBUG` to `True`. The easiest way to do this is to create a custom run configuration.

1. Run > Edit Configurations
2. Create a new configuration for django, by clicking on <kbd>+</kbd> and selecting django server:

[image]

3. Then, set a custom environment variable. You do this by clicking on the button next to `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`:

[image]

4. Next, add a new configuration variable by clicking the <kbd>+</kbd>

[image]

5. Click OK, and give your new configuration a name:

[image]

6. Click Apply then OK to dismiss the dialogues.
7. Edit your `settings.py` and add this:

   ```
   import os

   DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', False)
   ```

Now, simply select your new configuration from the Run menu when you want to run with debugging enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach for this is to have multiple Django settings files:

```
settings/
    base.py
    production.py
    development.py
    testing.py
```

then you can run `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.development manage.py runserver`.

PyCharm allows to pick the settings in run configurations too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [cookiecutter-duango](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to generate the project template when starting a new Django project. Your project can be configured for development with PyCharm and you get the both configurations, development (with DEBUG=True) and production (with DEBUG=False) automatically.